# SQL Server Manage Compression Inactive

Tags: sql-server, compression, sql-server-2016

I want to manage compression but when i press the database-tables and right click on the table name storage menu shows manage compression is inactive on my SQL server 2016. I have sysadmin privileges. How i can make it active ?
My autentication is windows authentication.

Comment: Do you have a database compatibility set to a previous version of SQL Server pre 2012?

Comment: There is a connect bug raised against SSMS 2016 release 16.4.1 see https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3104616. The fix is to use TSQL to set the compression. Also see changelog for release 16.5 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt588477.aspx

Comment: Yes Steve i have. I think you are right this is a unbeliavable bug cause i can do with tsql. Thank you so much. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a connect bug raised against SSMS 2016 release 16.4.1 see [connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3104616](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3104616).

The fix is to use TSQL to set the compression.

Also see changelog for release 16.5 [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt588477.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt588477.aspx)

TSQL Sample from MSDN:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
EXEC sp_estimate_data_compression_savings 'Production', 'TransactionHistory', NULL, NULL, 'ROW' ;  

ALTER TABLE Production.TransactionHistory REBUILD PARTITION = ALL  
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW);   
GO
```